# Datatables Export Customization not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

```
buttons: [
{   
    extend: "edit", 
        className: 'btn btn-primary bg-purple text-white',
        editor: editorEdit 
},
{
    extend: 'excelHtml5', 
    text: 'EXPORT', 
    filename: 'DataSet', 
    className: 'btn btn-primary bg-purple text-white',
    autoFilter: true,
    exportOptions: {
        modifier: {
            selected: true
        },
        columns: 'th:not(:first-child)'//[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ]
    },
    customize: function (xlsx) {
        var sheet = xlsx.xl.worksheets['sheet1.xml'];
        $('row:first c', sheet).attr('s','22');
    }
}]
```

However, the autoFilter and the customize options are not being reflected in the excel export.
Am I missing something or do I need to do it differently?

Comment: I commented out the "edit" button (I don't know what that is), but apart from that, your code [works correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6Cvc.png) for me. Can you provide a [mre] to help us recreate the issue?

Comment: @andrewJames Hi, I was able to resolve the issue. It was because of the older version of DataTables.

Comment: Glad you resolved it. You are welcome to [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), and explain exactly what changes you made - especially if you think it will help future visitors to this question.